# Is it possible to only load the contents of a tab if that tab has a certain class?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm looking for a way to make sure that my visitors don't have to download unnecessary data from my site, but I also want all the data to be available should the visitor decide to request it.

What I have done so far is to put all information in different tabs with the pure text information in the first tab. This works very well, the text appears first and the visitor is none the wiser. Problem is that the contents of the other tabs is read in the background and while this isn't a problem on fast T1-line, it's not good for any regular cell phone user. And to be honest, my web server wouldn't be sad if it didn't have to push 200 images to people who won't view them anyway.

What I have been trying to do is to stop the contents of tabs that don't have the class "uk-active" from being loaded. I browsed this great place of knowledge and I have found some solutions where each tab is a separate html page and then these are loaded into the tabs via ajax. The problem is that I can't really make such a setup without changing about everything on my site.

I have also seen examples on when images aren't loaded until they are in the viewport. Problem here is that the tab is in viewport and as such the images would start loading anyway (I think) and the other problem is that it's not just images, it is also videos, documents and pages after pages with rich text.

All my tabs are filled with different types of content so I have code that renders the correct number of tabs depending on if the different types of data exist. So, I need to run all this first so that the tabs are setup correctly and then, stop the tabs from being filled with the fetched data.

The different tabs have different code for loading the dynamic content, but one of the tab is only for images so let's start with that one.

I'm really sorry for the wall of text, it is just the context that might make it easier to help me... Now let's look at some code :)

My image gallery tab is populated by the following code

```
                ?>
                <div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-width-medium-1-2 uk-width-large-1-3">
                    <a class="uk-thumbnail uk-text-center" title="<?php echo $this->product->product_name; ?>" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'group1'}" href="<?php echo $image; ?>">
                       <img  width="auto" height="auto" alt="" src="<?php echo $image; ?>">
                    </a>
                </div>

            <?php
```

The $image is an array that is created by merging different arrays containing images of the following types (gif|GIF, jpg|JPG, png|PNG and svg).

The parent tab has the ID of "#prod_gallery" and when it is active it has the class ".uk-active".

So, I was thinking about a simple jQuery that would encase the above code and hold it from executing until `jQuery("#prod_gallery").hasClass("uk-active")` returns 'true'. It needs to check this both when the page is loaded and after the tabs are clicked.

So far so good, problem is however that I don't know how to write this code and/or if I'm at all looking at it from the right angle.

Any input that can point me in any direction of a solution would be most appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time and again, sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: I think the solution you're trying to accomplish is pretty similar to the ones you already described as too much work, just that you're trying to use JQuery to encapsulate the HTML instead of external files - in other words I don't think it will solve your problem. If the main concern is images, have you looked at a lazy load plugin? These only load your images when they're visible, and it's low effort for you (after including the script you usually just have to update your images, to change the src= attribute to a data attribute, you can probably do a global find and replace).

Comment: Thank you. I found this one: http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/ that I have installed and tested and that one works for the most part but I get a strange error that says that my urls cannot be read, but the urls are correct and when i paste them directly in the browser the images appear as they should. I'll investigate further but thank you for pointing me in this direction.